# removing \r\n\r\n at the very beginning AND at the very end in a string using r

Tags: r, string, data-cleaning

I want to remove \r\n\r\n  before and after each string in a column

```
df = data.frame(names = c("\r\n\r\n17-Hydroxyprogesterone\r\n\r\n", "\r\n\r\n5-HIAA\r\n\r\n", "\r\n\r\nAcetaminophen\r\n\r\n", "\r\n\r\nAcetylcholine Receptor (AChR) Antibody\r\n\r\n"))
```

Expected output

```
names
n17-Hydroxyprogesterone
5-HIAA
Acetaminophen
Acetylcholine Receptor (AChR) Antibody
```

Comment: Fairly straightforward.  What have you tried?

Comment: `df$names <- trimws(df$names)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Base R Try:

```
df$name <- gsub(“r\\n\\r\\n”, “”, df$name)
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
df <- df %>%
           mutate(name = gsub(“r\\n\\r\\n”, “”, name)
```

Comment: Or `"[\r\n]"` for `pattern`